# Javascript function call not executing

Tags: javascript

I have a function in pure JavaScript that flies out a div from the right. This could be written better, but I'm not worried about that right now.

If I manually call `flyout()`, it does what it's supposed to. If I call `nextStep()`, it does all the *other* stuff it's supposed to, except for calling `flyout()`.

These functions are in the same file.

```
function flyout() {
    window.phases.style.left = window.innerWidth - (window.phases.style.width.replace("px","").valueOf());
    window.flown = true;
    phasesName = document.getElementById("phasesName");
    phasesBody = document.getElementById("phasesBody");

    phasesName.style.display = "none";
    phasesBody.style.display = "block";
}


function nextStep() {
    switch (window.stepName) {
        case "Step1":
            stepName = "Step2";
            step2();
            break;

        case "Step2":
            stepName = "Step3";
            step3();
            break;

        case "Step3":
            stepName = "Step4";
            step4();
            break;

        case "Step4":
            stepName = "Step5";
            step4();
            break;
    };
    flyout();
}
```

It does everything I want it to, except for calling `flyout()` function.

Comment: Why are your steps all messed up?

Comment: check in the browser JS console if there is any JS error; step2/3/4... methods may be failing thereby skipping the flyout() call

Comment: It looks like it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/nT8Ha/1/

Comment: Where is this even defined...? `window.stepName`

Comment: if there is an error in any of your step functions, it will break the switch and never hit flyout. use the console!1

Comment: And if the window hasn't found that variable yet, how is it supposed to run a switch statement...? Maybe you know something I don't lol.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Sorry. I misread your comment. I thought you were asking why he user `window`. I will delete my comment because it made no sense. Ha. Time to go to sleep.

Comment: Farfromunique you will need to give us more of your code because as @DutGRIFF showed us the code works if there functions you have declared(step4(), step3(), step2()) don't error at any point. eg. they are trivial functions that don't disrupt execution.

Comment: Check your error console using F12 on Chrome (if your have firebug in Firefox). I thought your error code brake your execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser probably isn't getting down to the flyOut() call in nextStep(). Put console.log or alert about the flyOut() call in nextStep() and see if it is getting called.

Comment: This is more of a comment.

Comment: I can't mark my own answer as "answered" for a couple days, and you helped me find the issue (the alert showed me the error). Have rep!

Comment: @David Well there you go. Now you can comment. :)

Comment: @Farfromunique I'm happy I could help you! :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. it **is** firing off, but it's being countered by a different function call immediately.

FWIW, the project is at https://github.com/farfromunique/vampirrePoints/ and yes, i know I typo'd vampire.